# Angular Material Colors

Tags: angular, colors, angular-material

I know I can use colors in Angular Material like so

```
<button mat-button color="primary"></button>
```

I've got two questions which I couldn't find answered anywhere.

1. What controls other than button accept that color attribute?
2. What colors other than primary, secondary, accent and warn are possible?

I found the Material Color guide, that talked about a lot, but not about those two questions.

Answer (score 1):

There are no other possibilities in those components for the `color` attribute.

But there are other possibilities for the SCSS based on the colors you've chosen for primary, accent and warn. The variations can be accessed by using the `mat-color` mixin as the second parameter. By using the variations, you'll be keeping the material system recommendations.

About which controls have the `color` attribute: I guess all the controls at the "Buttons and Indicators" section along with the "Form  Controls" section on Angular material homepage (like everything else on @angular/material, it likely follows the Material Design recommendation for that).